# File not created (Linux-PHP-C++)

Tags: php, c++, linux

I am trying to save a file to the current directory in Linux and then display it on a webpage. Currently I run a C++ executable from a php script with the following code

```
exec("/var/www/html/radsim/plotFluence $rMin $rMax $zMin $zMax $lum $graphStyle      $basepath[$path]", $return);
```

When I run the executable from the console in Linux the file is created fine, the problem arises when I try from within the php; the file is simply not in the directory . The user inputs values and the executable is run but no file is made. The C++ looks like this

```
 canvas->Print(("/var/www/html/radsim/"+histoName+_FileFormat).c_str());
```

The permisions are set to 777.  In addition, on another PHP script, I use fopen("data.txt", 'w') or die() to create a text file, but it always dies.

Comment: Any chance you have a "hardy" version of Linux that forbids Apache-started processed from writing files (e.g. SELinux)? This may be of help then (or some other page found googling for "SELinux enable httpd write")
http://david-latham.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/allow-httpd-apache-to-write-to-files.html
(Or disable SELinux, which is a bad idea)

Comment: Currently I am running scientific Linux 6 with SELinux fully disabled

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a sandbox. There must be a php config option - best to start here: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php